# Batch tf.matmul of tensors with different ranks

Tags: python, tensorflow, linear-algebra

Given a Tensor of shape `(A, B, C, D, E)` and a tensor of shape `(A, B, E)`, I would like to do a batch multiplication with automatic broadcasting of the second tensor, such that:

```
    In [1]: X = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[A, B, C, D, E])
    In [2]: Y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[A, B, E])
    In [3]: # DO SOMETHING LIKE tf.matmul(X, Y)
    Out[3]: <tf.Tensor 'MatMul_1:0' shape=(A, B, C, D) dtype=float64>
```

Is it even possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Broadcasting is mostly supported for those operations which makes use of element-wise computation. `tf.matmul` is not element-wise operation but `tf.multiply` is element-wise based.

Also, Tensorflow may or may not do automatic broadcasting for higher order tensors even in those operations where broadcasting is supported. In those cases, you will manually have to do it.

I have written [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47520854/what-is-supported-by-broadcasting-in-tensorflow-how-dimensions-matches-determin/47528585#47528585) which does automatic broadcasting for higher order tensors.